# Flotation of a body which is submersed into a incompressible fluid using Archimedes principal

Tags: fluid-statics

There is a small boat in a water tank and the boat is loaded with a huge piece of rock .The water tank is totally filled with water .If the rock is taken off from the boat and totally submerged in the tank water then what will happen to the water level of the tank?

Answer (score 0):

If the rock is completely submerged the water will not fill the tank.

If we assume that the rock, in the idealized boat, weights 4000 kg and its volume is 1 m^3 then the situation is equivalent to filling the boat with 4 m^3 of water or adding 4 m^3 of water in the tank.

If the rock is submerged then the situation is equivalent to adding just 1 m^3 of water when 4 m^3 are needed to fill the tank.